# Нужен ли знак препинания? Подскажите, пожалуйста

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Нужен ли знак препинания? Возможно, тире?
Пример:

*Боец, воин, герой (?) исстари защищают города.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятая между однородным рядом подлежащих и сказуемым не нужна.

Возможна постановка тире:

***Боец, воин, герой — исстари защищают города.***

[**Интонационное тире**](https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=94) может отделять любую часть предложения.

> Тире ставится для указания места разделения простого предложения на словесные группы, чтобы подчеркнуть либо уточнить смысловые отношения между членами предложения, когда другими знаками препинания или порядком слов нужный смысл не может быть выражен.

P. S. Меня тоже изначально смутило лексическое несоответствие числа подлежащих и сказуемого, но я не стал на этом заострять внимание (что в очередной раз говорит о необходимости бережного отношения к каждому проявлению мысли, смысла, к тонкостям речи, стиля и пр. и пр.). И сейчас прихожу к такому варианту, где подлежащие можно рассмотреть не как отдельные субъекты, а как обозначение одного и того же понятия, и сказуемое поставить в единственное число:

***Боец, воин, герой исстари защищает города.***

Answer (score 5):

***Боец, воин, герой (?) исстари защищают города.***

1) Что можно сделать с этим предложением?

(1) ***Боец, воин, герой исстари защищают города.***

Нет, так не говорят. Здесь ед.число  употреблено в значении мн. числа [https://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/157/Употребление_единственного_числа_в_значении_множественного](https://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/157/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE)

Но в этом случае глагол ставится в ед. ч.: В такую вьюгу и медведь не вылезает из берлоги. А вот можно ли объединять такие сущ. в однородный ряд и использовать глагол во мн. числе? Мне такая фраза **кажется неестественной.**

Лучше так: ***Бойцы, воины и герои исстари защищают города.***

2) Ставить интонационное тире в любом месте, которое нам понравится, тоже неверно. Деление предложение на части должно быть осмысленным.

***Боец, воин, герой — исстари защищают города***. Нет, так мы тоже не говорим.

3) Единственный вариант — это именительный темы, там возможностей больше.

***Боец, воин, герой — они исстари защищают города.***

Comment: Да, конечно, все верно! Жаль, что я сомневалась (единственное или множественное). Жаль, что я не умею расставлять все точки — как Вы.

Comment: Sharon, к сожалению, Ваша ссылка не открывается, и это не только в этом ответе. Что делать?!

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Странно, у меня никогда не было сложностей с открытием ссылок. Боюсь. проблема где-то на Вашей стороне (хотя, ума не приложу...).

Comment: @grizzly Всё другое открывается, а тут пишет "не защищено". Хм...

Comment: У меня оикрылась.

Comment: Александр, я надеюсь, что вы нашли тему, там просто краткая информация, ничего особенного.

Comment: Риммочка, спасибо за ваш отзыв. Человеческая природа такова, что ее не исправишь. Как сказал наш великий баснописец, "хвалы приманчивы, как их не пожелать".